# can i reduce load time while creating pdf?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have created a PDF file with tcpdf.

For less data it works fine and not taking much time to get load, but if I write more data it takes one or two minutes to load.

Is there any solution?

My file contains only text, some colors on text and few images - nothing else. Still it takes much more time to load.

---

I am doing this:

```
$pdf->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $html, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);
$pdf->Output();
exit();
```

I found http://www.tcpdf.org/performances.php - maybe I have to implement xcache?

Comment: Where is the delay happening?

Comment: I am doing this $pdf->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $html, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true); $pdf->Output(); exit();

Comment: right and you've profiled it in xdebug and know exactly where the time is being consumed.  so focus on that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well and it didn't have anything to do with my code.  I was running Ubuntu Linux, a 32 bit version of the operating system.

I reinstalled and switched to the 64 bit version and the generation time went from 1 to 2 minutes down to 5 to 10 seconds.  Huge difference.